# function show in url after submit form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, url

When I submit this form all things are well n good but I want the controller function not shows in url. I want all things are done in same page. Still the url show

```
localhost/Naveen/CodeIgniter/welcome/insertform
```

but I don't want the form_open('') show's in url so how it is possible?

**controller welcome.php**

```
public function insertform()
{
    if (isset($_POST['mysmt']))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('femail', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fmobile', 'Mobile', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_view');
        }
        else
        {
            $_POST['fname'];
            $_POST['femail'];
            $_POST['fmobile'];
            if($this->test_model->insert('user_accounts',array('',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['femail'],$_POST['fmobile'])))
            {
                $success['success']="Thanks For Join Us";
                $this->load->view('welcome_view',$success);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_view');
    }
}
```

**view welcome_view.php**

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/insertform'); // ?>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php 
    if(isset($success))
    {?>
        <input type="button" class="form-control btn-success" value="<?php echo $success; ?>">
<?php }
    else
    {
        echo "";
    }?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Name <?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></label>
      <?php
      $entername = array(
          'name'        => 'fname',
          'value'       => '',
          'maxlength'   => '100',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter Name',
          'class'       => 'form-control',
        );
      echo form_input($entername); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Email <?php echo form_error('femail'); ?></label>
      <?php
      $enteremail = array(
          'name'        => 'femail',
          'value'       => '',
          'maxlength'   => '100',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter Email',
          'class'       => 'form-control',
        );
      echo form_input($enteremail); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Mobile <?php echo form_error('fmobile'); ?></label>
      <?php
      $entermobile = array(
          'name'        => 'fmobile',
          'value'       => '',
          'maxlength'   => '100',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter Mobile',
          'class'       => 'form-control',
        );
      echo form_input($entermobile); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php
      $f_formsmt = array(
          'name'        => 'mysmt',
          'value'       => 'Submit Form',
          'class'       => 'form-control btn btn-success',
        );
      echo form_submit($f_formsmt); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: its not working after blank form_open() I think without calling function it's not run but I can't show the function with any name

Comment: why I show function in url I want the function call but after submit the not go any function or anywhere link in core php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Answer (score 0):

You handle it through applications/config/routes.php

consider you url: `localhost/Naveen/CodeIgniter/welcome/insertform`

```
$route['add'] = 'welcome/insertform';
```

now you can use `localhost/Naveen/CodeIgniter/add`

You can change whatever the string you want for any controller/function using routes.

Hope you understood :)

Comment: I want to ask you that when I work on core php I give form action $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. is it not posible in codeigniter...?

Comment: I'm not sure. But if you put the action="", then it will be call back to the same function where its called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the url in route and add link to your link href

In route.php add:

```
$route['custom_url'] = 'controller/method';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `Header("location:../{whatever-filename}")`

Then gave that "whatever-filename" the proper routing in the config/routes.php.

Routing without using the redirect function would load the appropriate page but the url would still show the controller and method you're using.

Hope it helps